# Combine results from API into one object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am creating a simple api consumer application using asp.net mvc web api2 controllers.

The two get requests in my web api controller are as follows:

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetUsersAsync()
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(
                await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
            );
    }

}

public async Task<List<UserToDoList>> GetUserToDoListAsync()
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserToDoList>>(
                await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
            );
    }

}
```

This gives me List of two separate objects List of Users & List of User To Do's.

What is the best/fastest way to combine them so that I can show it in a tabular format like:

```
UserId  |  Name | Count Of Todo's
```

Comment: create an endpoint that combines the two calls and returns what you want

Comment: @Nkosi can you post a sample of code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the two calls and returns what you want either on the client side by calling your web apis or creating a new endpoint that merges the data and returns the combined data

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
    var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(
                    await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
                );
    var todos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserToDoList>>(
            await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
        );

    var result = from user in users
                 join todo in todos on user.UserId equals todo.UserId into userTodos
                 select new { UserId = user.UserId, Name = user.Name, CountOfTodos = userTodos.Count() };
}
```